# ConEmu Underlined Text appears as different color

Tags: conemu

I have ConEmu set up running Cygwin and using the Solarized colorscheme.  The only problem is that underlined text simply appears as normal text with a different color.

I am using Consolas, 16pt but I have tried other fonts and sizes with no luck.

FYI: On my Mintty terminal I get underlined text no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Up until recently, Windows Console didn't support underline, so this was the workaround baked into Cygwin (on clients) and Termcap (on servers).

The reason it works in Mintty is Cygwin applications have 2 operating modes:

- Windows Console (e.g. CMD, ConEmu)
- POSIX terminal (e.g. ssh, mintty)

ConEmu (CMD, PowerShell) would cause Cygwin apps to run in Windows Console mode. While Mintty would cause Cygwin apps to run in POSIX terminal mode.